# React useMemo on a function with return value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple function that has return values based on if statements. I need to useMemo on this function that keep the same values between renders. How can I do this?

```
const getStatusState = () => {
 if (a === 'STRING_A') {
  return 'duplicate';
 }
 if (a === 'STRING_B') {
  return 'good';
 }
return 'N/A';
};
```

How does useMemo work on this function as I am not using useState I am getting the value a from props.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap it with `React.useMemo` and pass `a` into the dependency array so it fires only if `a` changes.

```
const getStatusState = React.useMemo(() => {
   if (a === 'STRING_A') {
      return 'duplicate';
   }

   if (a === 'STRING_B') {
      return 'good';
   }

   return 'N/A';
}, [a]);
```

Comment: What if I leave the dependency array empty? It still only gets called once when I run the function.

Comment: @CHris905 If you leave the array empty it will get called only once.

Comment: The above is only valid if you want to use 'getStatusState' as a variable ie: 

console.log(getStatusState) => returns value of 'a'.



And if you call a function, it will give Error
console.log(getStatusState()) => > Uncaught TypeError: getStatusState is not a function

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is valid only if you want to use `getStatusState` as a constant. If you use `getStatusState` as a function it will give `Uncaught TypeError:` . ie: if you log below using the console

```
const getStatusState = React.useMemo(() => {
   if (a === 'STRING_A') {
      return 'duplicate';
   }

   if (a === 'STRING_B') {
      return 'good';
   }

   return 'N/A';
}, [a]);
```

Logs will be:

```
console.log(getStatusState); => 'STRING_A' or 'STRING_B' or 'N/A'
console.log(getStatusState()); => Uncaught TypeError: getStatusState is not a function
```

To solve the above problem and use `getStatusState` as function ie: `getStatusState()`, there are two ways in React:

1 Using  useMemo() and return a Function

```
const getStatusState = React.useMemo(
  () => () => {
    if (a === 'STRING_A') {
      return 'duplicate';
    }

    if (a === 'STRING_B') {
      return 'good';
    }

    return 'N/A';
  },
  [a]
);
```

2 Using useCallback()

```
const getStatusState = React.useCallback(() => {
  if (a === 'STRING_A') {
    return 'duplicate';
  }

  if (a === 'STRING_B') {
    return 'good';
  }

  return 'N/A';
}, [a]);
```